# Customise list forms using Napa

Tags: list-form

My organisation is using SharePoint Online (Enterprise plan - now upgraded to SP2013) and would like to customise a number of the OOTB list NewItem, EditItem and DisplayItem forms.

Given my experience leans towards HTML/Javascript I have a preference to utilise NAPA apps to provide me with the design experience I am after (although I can and do use SPD), and would also prefer not to use InfoPath.

I'd be grateful if someone could give some pointers as to how the completed NAPA app can subsequently be associated with the appropriate list event.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the following link and check 
http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Visual-Studio-Toolbox/Building-Office-and-SharePoint-Apps-with-Napa-and-Visual-Studio

Comment: Would you give more details into this instead of just a link?